# Is it possible to pass an unscoped enum to va_start?

Tags: c++, enums, c++17, language-lawyer, variadic-functions

## The Problem

I have a legacy codebase with something like this:

```
enum MyEnum { Foo, Bar, Baz };

void someFunc(MyEnum enumVal, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, enumVal); 
    // do something with args...
}
```

I cannot easily change `MyEnum` to a scoped enum, since it's used throughout our whole code base (some of which I don't even have access to). Compiling this code (with '-Wall -std=c++17'), Clang 14  emits this warning:

```
<source>:8:20: warning: passing an object that undergoes default argument promotion to 'va_start' has undefined behavior [-Wvarargs]
    va_start(args, enumVal);
```

As far as I can tell, the problem here is a combination of these three rules (or lack thereof, see the third point) in the C++ (17, but should be the same for 11 or 14) standard:

#### 1. Unscoped enums are (in a function call) always promoted to their underlying type.

The Integer Promotion rules `[conv.prom]` say:

> 3. A prvalue of an unscoped enumeration type whose underlying type is not fixed (7.2) can be converted to a prvalue of the first of the following types that can represent all the values of the enumeration: […]
> 4. A prvalue of an unscoped enumeration type whose underlying type is fixed (7.2) can be converted to a prvalue of its underlying type. […]

While these rules only state that there *can* be an integer conversion, `[expr.call]/7` says:

> If the argument has integral or enumeration type that is subject to the integral promotions […], the value of the argument is converted to the promoted type before the call.

So basically, any `enum` (that is not an `enum class`) must be promoted to its underlying type before call.

#### 2. `va_start` must take an argument that is 'compatible' to the resulting type

The rules for `va_start` in `[cstdarg.syn]/1` state:

> If the parameter parmN is […] of a type that is not compatible with the type that results when passing an argument for which there is no parameter, the behavior is undefined.

Here I'm not sure what the `type that results when passing an argument for which there is no parameter` means. I guess that it's the (promoted!) type of the `parmN` parameter when you specify at least one of the variadic parameters. Not sure why that influences the type of the `parmN` parameter, but basically I guess it means a call like

```
someFunc(MyEnum::Foo, 42);
```

In this case, `42` is the `argument for which there is no parameter`.

In any case, the type of the parameter passed to `va_start` is `MyEnum`, and the (promoted) type of the argument is some integer type. Leading to the third point:

#### 3. It is unclear what 'compatible' means in this context

While the C standard clearly states which types are 'compatible' (see `6.2.7 Compatible type and composite type` of the C standard), the C++17 standard explicitly states in its list of differences to C, in `[diff.basic]/6.9`:

> Change: C allows “compatible types” in several places, C++ does not.

And, consequently, does not give a specification of what 'compatible types' are. So to me, it's not clear how the 'compatible' requirement in `[support.runtime]/3` is to be interpreted. If we apply the old C-standard rules of compatibility, I guess that `enum`s are only ever compatible to `enum`s, not to `int`s.

If that is a correct interpretation, I see no way of using an unscoped `enum` parameter in `va_start`.

## The Question

Is there, in C++17, a non-undefined-behavior way of passing an unscoped `enum` parameter of a function to `va_start`? Or, phrased differently: Given a variadic function which has an unscoped `enum` parameter as its last named parameter (before the `...`), is there a way of retrieving the `va_list`?

Comment: Could just cast it to / from an `int`, since `va_args` is inherently not typesafe anyway

Comment: As workaround, there is still `void someFuncImpl(std::underlying_type_t<MyEnum> enumVal, ...); template <typename ...Ts> void someFunc(MyEnum e, Ts...args) { someFuncImpl(std::underlying_type_t<MyEnum>{e}, args...) }`.

Comment: I would say that you should avoid to use ..., va_start and other legacy stuff in modern C++ as it is very error prone if someone pass the wrong argument type, the compiler and runtime would not detect it and you would have undefined behavior. You should use variadic template instead.

Answer (score 1):

> Here I'm not sure what "the type that results when passing an argument for which there is no parameter" means.

It means the type that `enumVal` would be passed as in ellipsis. This is defined at http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.call#11.sentence-1 :

> When there is no parameter for a given argument, the argument is passed in such a way that the receiving function can obtain the value of the argument by invoking `va_arg`.

In other words, you can write `va_start(args, arg)` if `arg` is of a type `T` such that, if `arg` had instead been passed in ellipsis, `va_arg(args, T)` would be valid.

> Given a variadic function which has an unscoped enum parameter as its last named parameter (before the ...), is there a way of retrieving the va_list?

No. Perhaps you could move the offending function to a C source file. Otherwise, you could wait for C++ to adopt C23 unary `va_start`. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/variadic/va_start

Answer (score 1):

You could simply change the declaration of someFunc to take an `int`:

```
void someFunc(int enumVal, ...)
```

Now all the call sites will implictly convert the enum tag to int (which is what happens anyways for default argument promotion), and the type is correct within the function for calling `va_start`